# How do I use the z-index properly?

Tags: html, css

See this page here:

http://www.blakearchive.org/blake/public/exhibits/canterburySpecial.html

The menu bar is supposed to go above the text and the red and black gallery menu on the right should go over the menu bar and text.

I've set the z-index for the right column (in which the text sits) and the menu bar to 1, and the z-index of the red and black gallery menu to -1. But the divs still still next to each other, rather than on top of each other as they're supposed to.

The relative css is here:

```css
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-top: 5px solid #823
    z-index: 1;
}
#columns .right {
    float: right;
    width: 28%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    text-align: justify;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menubar {
    float: right;
    width: 18%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps worth checking out: [What noone told you about Z-index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `z-index` property will only work when there is also a `position` property applied (not counting `position: static;`, which is the default).

All of the following will work, according to the spec:

```css
position: fixed;
position: absolute;
position: relative;
position: sticky; /* Limited support, currently in Firefox and Opera */
```

The only exceptions are within a [`flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting) container or a CSS [`grid`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order).

Comment: I set the position to relative upon initializing the page. I just tried setting it in the css, but I still get the same result.

Comment: @user2697528 `position: relative;` positions your element relative to its parent element. If the parent element is not positioned, then it can cause problems. The z-index simply won't apply unless there is a `position` property set in the CSS.

Comment: The parent element of the menu bar is set to relative position. And the red and black menu bar is set to relative as well. Do I need to set the children of the menu bar to relative? I tried that as well, but no change.

Comment: @user2697528 generally when you have an element's position set to `relative`, I think you need to set its parent to `absolute`. I'm not intimately familiar with the `position` properties.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I tried that as well. There must be something else that's off in my html. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4):

[`z-index` applies to *positioned elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index).

Positioned elements are [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioned-element) as elements for which the `position` property has a value other than `static`.

`static` is the default value.

You haven't applied a different `position` value to any of your elements.

You probably want `position: relative;`.

Comment: I set the position to relative upon initializing the page. I just tried setting it in the css, but I still get the same result. See the page now. Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: This is not a full answer: "But the divs still still next to each other, rather than on top of each other as they're supposed to."  Looks like he needs some positioning/layout help as well.

Comment: @user2697528 — https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/817e44dd-fd38-4d6f-89aa-be4c7433269c/b2452eb775bfc0a537c9982c747ee932 - use a validator.

Comment: @Ennui, I think you're right; there must be something else that's off in my html. I'm stumped.

Comment: Problem solved: There was a parent element that didn't have a set position. I've been overlooking it for days! Thanks for everyone's help.